# How do iteratively add to a list of Corpora while preserving its type in R?

Tags: r, tm

I have a list of n documents that I'm trying to iterate through add together so they form a single VCorpus. Normally you can use the `c()` operator and join two VCorpus to create a bigger one. But if I initialise the list first as I do below it casts the corpora into a character list. But if I  don't initialise it first I get an error.

```
  clean_corpus <- c()
  for (i in directory_source$filelist) {
    conn <- file(i,"r")
    filebuffer <- readLines(conn, encoding="UTF-8", skipNul=TRUE)
    close(conn)

    set.seed(3413)
    sampled_buffer <- sample(filebuffer, size = round(length(filebuffer) * fraction, digits = 0))
    sample_corpus <- VCorpus(VectorSource(sampled_buffer))
    clean_corpus <- c(clean_corpus, sample_corpus, recursive = TRUE)
  }
```

Comment: After typing this out. I guess an if statement could probably fix this. But I wonder if there's a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 0):

It's not tested but it may work:

```
f <- function(i){conn <- file(i,"r")
                 filebuffer <- readLines(conn, encoding="UTF-8", skipNul=TRUE)
                 close(conn)  
                 set.seed(3413)
                 sampled_buffer <- sample(filebuffer, size = round(length(filebuffer) * fraction, digits = 0))
                 sample_corpus <- VCorpus(VectorSource(sampled_buffer))
                 clean_corpus <- c(clean_corpus, sample_corpus, recursive = TRUE)}

corpus_list <- lapply(directory_source$filelist,f)
corpus_agg  <- do.call(c,corpus_list)
```